# Obtner el id en un datatable que esta paginado

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo un datatable q muestra 191 registros en 20 paginas, se encuentra paginado de 10 en 10. Tengo un boton edit en el que doy clic y levanta un modal para cambiar un valor en la bd, me funciona bien para la primera pagina pero en las demas no.
codigo del datatable

```
<table id="bootstrap-data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Carnet ID</th>
                        <th>Cuenta</th>
                        <th>Salario</th>
                        <th>Operación</th>

                      </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                    <?php

                    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM cuc";
                    $stmt = $db->prepare( $query2 );
                    $stmt->execute();

                    while ($row =$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
                        extract($row);

                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <?php echo "<td>{$row['nombre']}</td>" ?>
                            <?php echo "<td>{$row['num_ci']}</td>" ?>
                            <?php echo "<td>{$row['cuenta']}</td>" ?>
                            <?php echo "<td>{$row['impote']}</td>" ?>
                            <?php echo '<td><span ><button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm modal-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRow" data-id="' . $row['id'] . '">' .
                                   '<span class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></span>' .
                                '</td>';?>



                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                    //

                    ?>

                    </tbody>
                  </table>

Asi tomo el valor del elemento  q seleccione para lebvantar el modal
  <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.modal-button').on('click', function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        $('#campo_id').val($this.data('id'));
                    });
                })
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#bootstrap-data-table').on('click', '.modal-button', function () {
         var $this = $(this);
         $('#campo_id').val($this.data('id'));
    });
})
```

Comment: que le sirva de ayuda otros también. Gracias comunidad por existir, y a ti alanfcm

Comment: Hola Alan. Recuerda no decir solo "intenta". Explica lo que está mal en la pregunta y cómo tu codigo funciona y lo soluciona. Si no es para el OP, para futuros usuarios que puede que no comprendan tu codigo. Un saludo !